# Site to site VPN setup

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ddns

I have two sites with cable modems at each location. 
Each has an Engenius ESR-600H VPN router. Dynamic addresses.

I have an account at DYN which is supported by the Engenius unit. I haven't gotten that to work yet. But I will.,

That Engenius router has only a VPN server, no client. 
I have the VPN set up at one site, and I can connect to it from my android phone. I have not yet been able to connect to it with quickvpn on a laptop, and since I am on the same network that might be the problem. Well, or maybe not.

I am going to take the laptop to another location and see if I can connect. But I think I have verified the VPN server is working at one site.

At the other site I have some computers which can mostly use their local wan. Some devices that are at that location I want to use the remote WAN only.

So what I have is a Cisco RV082, which I think has a flexible enough support for DDNS that I can configure it to be able to find it's server at the other site. I set up an account at DuckDNS that should be able to be configured in the Cisco unit.  And it does have a VPN client that should be able to connect to the other site.

This is all a little confusing. How can I put this on my second site and have some devices (not necessarily computers) connect to it instead of the Engenius router and so will come out at the first site and use the wan there?

I'm thinking I can configure the units that I want to use the remote WAN with a different gateway, the gateway of the Cisco RV082, which can then connect out through the Engenius unit to the remote site.

I am also unsure exactly how to set up the incoming vpn traffic to go out through the remote WAN.  A static route in the Engenius unit at site one?

Comment: A big wall of text like this isn't super helpful in the SU question+answer format. You're better off using bullet points and lists. If the Engenius is host only then you'll want to run the VPN server there, then access its dynamic host name from the cisco(ensure they support the same protocols). Once that works, then you'll want to start redirecting traffic from remote clients through the VPN.

Comment: I have two of the cisco boxes, I might end up using two of those. There's also a writeup on a bridged open VPN tunnel between two DDWRT boxes. I have some of those too.

Comment: But if I do that what makes the devices at the other end use the wan at the site where the VPN server is?  There are no network resources there that they need, they just need the remote WAN.  

I am just not clear on how to send the remote traffic out the WAN.